# Is it possible to express $\Gamma\!\left(\tfrac{1}{50}\right)$ through values of the $\Gamma$-function at rational points with smaller denominators?

Tags: special-functions, gamma-function, rational-numbers

Sometimes it is possible to express a value of the $\Gamma$-function at a rational point through values of the $\Gamma$-function at rational points with smaller denominators, e.g.
$$\Gamma\!\left(\tfrac{1}{10}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5}}}{2^{7/10}\sqrt{\pi}}\Gamma\!\left(\tfrac{1}{5}\right)\Gamma\!\left(\tfrac{2}{5}\right).$$
Is it possible to do that with $\Gamma\!\left(\tfrac{1}{50}\right)$?

Answer (score 4):

By the duplication formula,
$$\Gamma\left(\frac{2}{50}\right) = C\cdot \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{50}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{13}{25}\right)$$
hence:
$$\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{50}\right) = \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{25}\right)}{C\cdot \Gamma\left(\frac{13}{25}\right)}.$$

Specifically, the constant $C$ is,

$$\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{50}\right) = 2^{24/25}\sqrt{\pi}\, \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{25}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{13}{25}\right)} = 49.44221\dots$$

Comment: I took the liberty of adding $C$.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII: well done.